# AngularJS - How to fetch PDFs (or other binary files) from rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm writing a toy application to get acquainted with AngularJS. This application has a Rails backend.

I don't know how to make the client side angularjs app, deal with a PDF that the backend sends when hitting a particular URL (http://localhost:3000/contacts.pdf)

When typing the above mentioned URL straight in the browser, the server replies with a PDF and the browser asks what to do with it (download or open).

When the same thing is done via the angularjs app, I can see the file gets returned in the response. And that's where I'm stuck at.

How can I replicate the same behaviour within client side app?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is just use an anchor tag in HTML and put the link as a controller variable ie. `<a href="{{link}}">Download</a>` and in controller put $scope.link = "http://localhost..."; (or array if requiring multiple links).

If this is not what you want, please add further clarification.

Comment: A better thing to do is to use ng-href, this will ensure binding has happened.